# Unable to connect to Redis server running on Google Cloud VM with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to connect to a Redis server running on a Google Cloud VM using Node.js. The VM is running Redis and listening on port 6379. I have set up the appropriate firewall rules, and I can connect to the VM using an external machine. However, when I try to connect to Redis using my Node.js application, I get the following error:

```
errno: -61,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 6379
```

```
this.client = redis.createClient({
  host: redisIP,
  port: 6379,
  connectTimeout: 3000,
});
```

I'm certain that the firewall rules are working because I can successfully connect using `nc -vz <vm_external_ip> 6379`.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting an ECONNREFUSED error when trying to connect to my Redis server from my Node.js application, despite having the Redis server set to bind to all IP addresses (`bind *` in `/etc/redis/redis.conf`)?

Comment: **Replacing localhost by 127.0.0.1 may fix the issue**, but I think localhost now resolves to ::1(IPv6) instead of 127.0.0.1 (IPv4). Maybe that's why the CLI thinks the emulator is not yet ready.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy not sure I understand your comment- can you explain more? Redis isnt running locally, its running on a cloud vm, so that's why the host value is an external IP address. Let me know if theres more I can explain- not sure why localhost can affect this, or how to replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 for that matter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, are you binding to `::1` in `redis.conf?`.  Also are you trying to connect using a user that has no password / the default user with no password?  You'll need to set `protected-mode no` in `redis.conf` too.

See https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/

You should also consider using a named ACL user and password when exposing Redis like this. https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/

Comment: I'm seeing `bind * -::*` in the docs which must have been the problem- I had already changed protected mode to no. You're right about the ACL user/password, took less than a day for my VM to be infected with malware (Kinsing):
https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/kinsing-the-malware-with-two-faces

Needless to say I deleted the VM and am in the process of setting up a more secure one, thank you for your answer