# Unable to connect to Redis server on Google Cloud VM instance with port 6379

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, redis

I'm currently having an issue with port 6379 on Redis while using Google Cloud. I've set up a firewall rule to allow traffic on this port, but it still appears to be closed when I try to connect to Redis remotely. I've also checked that Redis is properly installed and running on the server, but still no luck.

I'm not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this issue. Can anyone offer some advice on what else to check or how to properly open port 6379 on Redis using Google Cloud?

I am using a VM on Google Cloud to host my application based on debian:buster

[image]

I have tried to open port 6379 for Redis on Google Cloud using the firewall rules, but even after adding the rule, the port remains closed. I have also checked the status of the Redis service and it is failing to start. I have tried to start it manually but it still fails. I have also checked the configuration file for Redis and it seems to be correct. I am currently unsure of what else I can do to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you find solution to this yet? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the error you are getting while connecting to the redis port and also look into the below which might give you some insights on this issue :

- Make sure the compute engine vm should use the same authorized
  network as your Redis instance. Try to set up again by using this
  [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-gce).
- Can you cross check whether the redis is properly configured in the
  configuration file as per this [redis official configuration file](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/), usually located at /etc/redis/redis.conf to listen on port 6379 .
- Refer to this firewall rules [troubleshooting doc](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/troubleshoot-issues#firewall_rules_block_your_instance_ip_addresses)

Comment: @koda777 : Is your issue resolved ? if not let me know , i will  assist on this.

Comment: @helman-kumar do you have an answer specific to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @ArlanG : refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804129/19230181) by Simon Prickett. Might help you.

Comment: @helman-kumar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824363/unable-to-connect-2-different-services-on-different-clusters-on-the-same-project) is my issue explained