# Unable to connect 2 different services on different clusters on the same project to Redis instace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, cluster-computing

I'm trying to connect **2** **different** **services** on **different clusters** on the **same project** to a **Redis instance** on one of the clusters on **GCP** with no luck. The services that shared the same cluster (A) have access to Redis using the IP assigned. But the other service on the other cluster (B) cannot access it. they use the default network, I have the redis-peer-erweqwewe23we activated.

- I tried to access the ip directly creating a firewall rule to access the network, but nothing.
- I also created a VM (redis-forwarder) to work as a forwarder to use the peer to connect the rule to the redis but nothing either.

Please, some advice would be appreciated

Comment: Details are required instead of generalizations.

Comment: What other details you required @JohnHanley???

Comment: Review your post. Can you reproduce the problem with the details you posted? Start with showing how everything is configured and the method you are using to connect with results/error messages.

Comment: IDK how to explain this, I'm new on this matter and I didn't find any solution online or on any other source. That's why I posted the things that I can share here.

Comment: Without details, how can we help you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask